# Where do I set the conditional e-mail recipients?

Tags: webforms

I need to set-up an auto response email/and submission page specifically for only three countries out of a list of many.

So, if someone selects (is from) country x, y or z, they see a different confirmation page and the form results are sent to two specific, unique addresses.

Otherwise, the form does what it is doing now which is displaying the confirmation message under Webform Settings.

I'm not sure about the conditional email recipients. Do I edit the actual "Country" form component and check E-mail a submission copy? But then, where do I actually enter something like AU|thisperson@example.com?

If I 'configure' the actual form, when I click "country" under the Conditional e-mail recipients, no additional fields appear for me to enter AU|thisperson@example.com

So I'm confused as to where to put the logic for the form to send a unique response page as well as specific email addresses only when a user from either x,y,z country?

I'm not fluent in php but thought I would need to put a comparison of the [country_code] and if it was either x/y/z then....what? Is there a specific call to a mail function? And as to adding the text for this secondary submission confirmation, I've no idea where to put that.